# Using rattle library on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, decision-tree, shiny

I'm trying to deploy an application on `shinyapps.io` using `rattle` for decision tree visualisation. Deploying on `shinyapps` server fails showing this:

> Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task ######### failed: Error building image: Error building RGtk2 (2.20.31). Build exited with non-zero status: 1

Does anyone have a solution for installing `RGtk2` on `shinyapps`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems to be impossible.
The only solution i found was to use `prp` library which seems to be a good alternative.